# Comparing two Big O notations

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

Please, could you help me with the question below.
Demonstrate that O(log n^k) = O(log n):

Comment: $\log n^k = k \log n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using properties of logs, log(n^k) can easily be transformed into *k*log(n). Then, because constant factors 'small out' as it were when using big O notation, O(*k*log(n))= O(log(n)).

Thus, O(log(n^k)) = O(*k*log(n)) = O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\log \left(n^k \right)=k\log \left(n \right).
$$